# How could one export from a sourced script only specific functions

Tags: bash, scripts, environment, functions

I try to expose from a script only specific functions.
For example, let's say I have the script `hello_world.sh` and it has 2 functions, `hello` and `world`:

```
## hello_world.sh - name of the file, not the beginning of file
hello() { echo "Hello"; }
world() { echo "World"; }
```

I want the script `use.sh` to export only the function I ask for, example `hello`. For this I would call the function `use` from `use.sh` with a parameter to tell it which function I desire to have exported:
`unset use hello world; . use.sh && use hello && hello && echo "Should succeed"`
`world || echo "Should fail and reach here because there is no such function"`

I would like to avoid storing the functions in temporary files in order to isolate better different (ba)sh environments.
Storing in a temporary file could look something like this:

```
## use.sh - name of the file, not the beginning of file
#! /bin/sh

use() {
  local env_file="$(/bin/mktemp)"
  (. ./hello_world.sh; declare -pfx "$@") > "${env_file}"
  . "${env_file}"
  /bin/rm -f "${env_file}"
}
```

How could I instead not create files(it feels like some kind of work-around) and expose directly the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), so that `use` would look like:

```
use() {  
  . <(. ./hello_world.sh; declare -f "$@")
}
```

Side note:

- `declare` is not POSIX, `/bin/sh` may not support it, so `use.sh` shouldn't have `/bin/sh` in the shebang. (Not that it matters much, since `use.sh` is sourced instead of executed.)

Comment: It works, thanks!
I tried doing this but I was leaving a space between "<" and "(", didn't know that it makes a difference.